# Outlook mail ID to communicate with Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook Add-in mailitem that I need to find the ID, so I can us it to communicate with Microsoft Graph.

The mailitem EntryID is not the same as the Microsoft Graph message ID.

Only way I figure out to do it, is to get the PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID like this:

```
Public Shared Function GetInternetMessageID(ByRef mail As MailItem) As String
    Try
        Dim s As String = mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F").ToString.ToLower.Replace(vbCrLf, " ").Replace("  ", "").Replace("message-id:<", "message-id: <")
        Return "<" + s.GetInnerString("message-id: <", ">") + ">"
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        Return String.Empty
    End Try
End Function
```

And then get the message from Graph like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '<HE1AR0301DD2555F3F27E45C4E1100@HE1PR1301MB2255.eurprd03.prod.outlook.com>'
```

But getting the "PropertyAccessor.GetProperty" from the code above is slow - takes like 3-4 seconds.

So now I have three IDs that is different:

- MailItem EntryID
- PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID
- Graph Message ID

Hmmmm.

Can I look up a Graph message using the mailitem EntryID? ... or can I find the Graph message ID in the Outlook mailitem?

How do you guys use Outlook Add-in mailitem and look up items in the Microsoft Graph for this mailitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found is to convert the MAPI entry id to EWS id using the ConvertId EWS operation, and then replace "+" with "_" and "/" with "-".

Comment: Well as I understand, Microsoft is shutting down EWS in near future in favor of Graph. I whish that the Outlook team and Graph team started to work together ... sigh.

Comment: Well, not exactly - my rule of thumb is to do what Outlook itself does. At the moment it only uses EWS (besides MAPI of course). When they switch away from EWS to Graph, then I will upgrade my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the translateExchangeIds graph service to convert between entryId and restId.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

This post might help.

https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/2744/converting-item-and-folder-ids-via-the-graph-api

```
#Graph uses URL-safe encoding, work around it
$sourceID = ("AAAAAEI4ipo6z2ZLl269wbCQeHMHACD+gIoVTa5CpTqvk1wNXAAAAAAAAQwAACD+gIoVTa5CpTqvk1wNXAAAAq2DE+kAAA==" -replace "\+","-") -replace "/","_"
$countToReplace = ($sourceID.ToCharArray() | ? {$_ -eq "="}).Count
$sourceID = $sourceID.TrimEnd("=") + $countToReplace
 
$body = @{
"inputIds"= @($sourceID)
"sourceIdType"= "entryId"
"targetIdType"= "ewsId"
} | ConvertTo-Json
$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sharednew@Michev.info/translateExchangeIds" -Headers $authHeader -Verbose -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
$res.value.targetId
 
$body = @{
"inputIds"= @($sourceID)
"sourceIdType"= "entryId"
"targetIdType"= "immutableEntryId"
} | ConvertTo-Json
$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sharednew@Michev.info/translateExchangeIds" -Headers $authHeader -Verbose -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
$res.value.targetId
 
AAMkADQxMTViNmEzLWViNWYtNGYxNy1iNmQ2LTZmNDVhN2Q5ZDI0NQBGAAAAAABCOIqaOs9mS5duvcGwkHhzBwAg/oCKFU2uQqU6r5NcDVwAAAAAAAEMAAAg/oCKFU2uQqU6r5NcDVwAAAKtgxPpAAA=
 
AAAAAB2EAxGqZhHNm8gAqgAvxFoNACD-gIoVTa5CpTqvk1wNXAAAAq2DORgAAA2
```